# Seeking a visual scripting environment

Tags: windows, gratis, ide, scripting

I am looking for a [Visual Scripting IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language). Since there are too many for me to try each out in depth, given my current crushing deadlines, I will specify as much as I can and hope for a reply from ***someone who has experience*** of the solution which they recommend.

I have to develop a test engine for our software. Users of all kinds should be able to specify and run test scripts. As many of them are non-technical, I thought of the kid's visual programming language "[Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/)" from MIT, which is simple to use, but quite powerful.

Users drag and drop icons to create programs, such as this traditional example:
[image]
The language has some standard programming concepts, such as branching and looping.

I am unsure whether it is extensible to add my own keywords and actions, so I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202259/mit-scratch-adding-removing-language-features) to try to find out.

I suppose that I can, since it is FOSS, but that might be a major effort.

So, does anyone have experience of a VPl which they can recommend?

Features:

- gratis ***for commercial use*** (open source a bonus)
- runs on Windows (Linux a bonus)
- visual programming IDE
- non-threatening to non-techies
- supports branching and looping
- allows adding keywords (in fact, I require no built-in keywords; I am willing to provide them all, plus back-end code. I just want the nice IDE, with drag and drop scripting of the keywords)
- can run external programs
- completed scripts ***must*** be runnable from the command line, for automation

Nice to have:

- generates output in a scripting language such as Python
- possible for programmers to directly code in the IDE's scripting language - without the IDE - and then run the scripts

---

[Update] I have just found Google's [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/)

> Blockly was influenced by [App Inventor](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/), which in turn was influenced
>   by [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/), which in turn was influenced by [StarLogo](http://education.mit.edu/projects/starlogo-tng).

It looks very promising. Especially when it says

> - Exportable code. Users can extract their programs as JavaScript,    Python, PHP, Dart or other language so that when they outgrow Blockly 
>     they can keep learning.
> - Open source. Everything about Blockly is    open: you can fork it, hack it, and use it in your own websites.
> - Extensible. Make Blockly fit with your application by adding custom    blocks for your API and remove unneeded blocks and
>     functionality.

One possible snag is that it is browser based, but if my management don't like that, then I can create a dummy Windows based app consisting of little but a TWebBrowser component.

I will investigate and report back - unless someone else posts an acceptable answer first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone with Blockly, which completely meets my needs. See question for details. Further research has failed to uncover anything which even comes close.

Comment: If you want it as an application, you could try [Nw.js](http://nwjs.io/) or [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)...

Comment: I was thinking of coding my app in Python and getting the browser component from tkinter (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). Those allow look useful. Thanks (+1)